# Regex to capture a group but exclude certain phrases

Tags: java, regex

I can't seem to get the lookahead right for this and it's absolutely driving me bonkers.

https://regex101.com/r/mW8lV6/6

In group 3's I want to match what I'm matching, but only group in a single group everything BUT `a|an|the|of` etc.

Ideally I would want group 3 to look like

```
hypnotic great mace resolution
```

This is the regex:

```
^You (grab|remove) (?:\( ([a-z]+) \) )?(?:\< [a-z]+? \> )?(?:\b(?!of)(.+?)\b) (?:which you held in|with) your (right|left).+?\.
```

This is the sample text:

```
You grab ( phasing ) < crafted > a hypnotic great mace of resolution which you held in your right mystical hand.
You grab ( pulsating ) < crafted > a superb hypnotic great mace with your left mystical hand.
You grab < crafted > a superb hypnotic great mace with your left mystical hand.  
You grab the Tempalus with your right stony hand.
You grab ( glossy ) the Tempalus of Doom with your right stony hand.
You grab ( glossy ) Uki's staff of the ataghan with your right hand.
You grab ( glossy ) Ocel-laris's staff of the ataghan with your right hand.
You grab Tempalus with your right stony hand.
You grab Tempalus, sword of judgement with your left mystical hand.
```

This is what the capture groups currently look like now:

- Group 1

```
remove
```

- Group 2

```
phasing
```

- Group 3

```
a hypnotic great mace of resolution
```

- Group 4

```
right
```

Comment: It can’t be done. Regex doesn't “do” anything, except match, so it can’t “remove” certain parts from the matched input. For that you’ll need app code. Use regex to extract that part you’re interested in, then use app code to mutate it (in this case removing the uninteresting parts of the interesting input).

Comment: While I understand that, I don't understand how we can't match the relevant parts we need using lookahead/lookbehinds into a capture group? If we have to separate into multiple sub capture groups and combine them into one overarching capture group is why I don't see it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the updated regex that solved my issue. Much thanks for the help getting me 95% of the way there.

```
^You (grab|remove) (?:\( ([a-z]+ )\) )?(?:< [a-z]+ > )?\b(?:(?:an?|the|of) )?((?!,)[A-Za-z'-]+)\,? ?((?:(?!(?:an?|the|of)\s)[A-Za-z'\-]+?\s)*)(?:(?:an?|the|of(?:\sthe)?) )?(?:(.+?)?\s)(?:which you held in|with) your (right|left).+?\.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex with slightly refactored groupings:

```
^You (grab|remove) (?:\( ([a-z]+) \) )?(?:< [a-z]+? > )?\b(?:(?:an?|the) )?(.+?)\b (?:which you held in|with) your (right|left).+?\.
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW8lV6/9)

Before start of group #3 we match `a, an, the` words in a non-capturing *optional* group and then match remaining text in group #3.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking to do, that just removes the preceding a|an|the|of and not all instances of the a|an|the|of words within the group 3.

Comment: I'm trying to remove ALL instances of a|an|the|of from the entire group, not just the first instance of it.
`a hypnotic great mace of resolution`
`hypnotic great mace resolution`

Comment: Can't we also say to skip any instance of a character group or matching pattern within a group? Thus the forward lookup problems.

Comment: Can you show me how with two seperate groups, keeping in mind it would need to match all the shown text?

Comment: How would I go about adding a comma into the regex? For the text of: `You grab Tempalus, sword of judgement with your left mystical hand.`

Comment: please check this new demo: https://regex101.com/r/mW8lV6/12

Comment: It didn't. This is the modified code `^You (grab|remove) (?:\( ([a-z]+ )\) )?(?:< [a-z]+ > )?\b(?:(?:an?|the|of) )?((?!,)[A-Za-z'-]+)\,? ?((?:(?!(?:an?|the|of)\s)[A-Za-z'\-]+?\s)*)(?:(?:an?|the|of(?:\sthe)?) )?(?:(.+?)?\s)(?:which you held in|with) your (right|left).+?\.`

Comment: Which is very similar to what I had here